# [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function: SyntaxError: Unexpected string in

Tags: vue.js

ocaasionaly this error came when i wrote code for input tags for keyup and keypress event and their corresponding vue code it was working but when i wrote
next input tag for keydown event and their correspoding vue code i got an error
like

till two input i have run this code earlier so i removed my new code and their corresponding vue code and than i again run but now i am still getting error in my correct previous code also

//leckeyboadevent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myapp">
        <input type="text" placeholder="keypress"  @keypress="keypressfun" >
        <br\>

        <input type="text" placeholder="keyup" @keyup="keyupfun">
        <br\>

        <input type="text" placeholder="keydown" @keydown="keydownfun">

    </div>
    <script src="lec6keyboardevent.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//this my js file

```
var myapp=new Vue({
    el:"#myapp",
    data:{

    },
    methods:{
        keypressfun:function(event){
            console.log(event.key);
        },
        keyupfun:function(event)//this works when key release
        {
            console.log(event);
        },
        keydownfun:function()
        {
            console.log("keydown");
        }
    }
});

i am getting error 
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:

SyntaxError: Unexpected string in

with(this){return _c('div',{attrs:{"id":"myapp"}},[_c('input',{attrs:{"type":"text","placeholder":"keypress"},on:{"keypress":keypressfun}}),_v(" "),_c('br',{attrs:{"\":""}}),_v(" "),_c('input',{attrs:{"type":"text","placeholder":"keyup"},on:{"keyup":keyupfun}}),_v(" "),_c('br',{attrs:{"\":""}}),_v(" "),_c('input',{attrs:{"type":"text","placeholder":"keydown"},on:{"keydown":keydownfun}}),_v(" "),_c('br'),_c('br')])}


(found in <Root>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @user9083922 I think the problem is how you are closing your html tags. 
Have you tried to close the br tags this standard way `<br/>` instead of `<br\>`?

It should work with this change.

In addition, if you want, `<br>` tags doesn't need to be closed in html5 as they are void elements.

For more info you can check: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements

Comment: This is indeed the reason why Vue gets upset, it tries to generate a method to render things in the vue way, but the \ from the malformed br tag escapes a closing quote, causing the problem